# How use attribute python

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

I have an attribute problem on my code.
I know it's a noob problem, but I'm a noob so ... :)

Code with sql selection :

```
import mysql.connector
from Constant import *
```

class mysql_select:

```
def select_category(self):
    connexion_data_base = mysql.connector.connect(user=MYSQL_USER, password=MYSQL_PWD, host=MYSQL_HOST, database=MYSQL_DATABASE)
    cursor = connexion_data_base.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT category FROM Category")
    self.data_category = cursor.fetchall()
    self.data_category = [d[0] for d in self.data_category] 
    return self.data_category

def select_food(self, idCategory):
    connexion_data_base = mysql.connector.connect(user=MYSQL_USER, password=MYSQL_PWD, host=MYSQL_HOST, database=MYSQL_DATABASE)
    cursor = connexion_data_base.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT food FROM Food WHERE idCategory ="+idCategory)
    self.data_food = cursor.fetchall()
    self.data_food = [d[0] for d in self.data_food]
    return self.data_food

def select_substitute(self, idCategory):
    connexion_data_base = mysql.connector.connect(user=MYSQL_USER, password=MYSQL_PWD, host=MYSQL_HOST, database=MYSQL_DATABASE)
    cursor = connexion_data_base.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT substitute FROM Substitute WHERE idCategory="+idCategory)
    self.data_susbstitute = cursor.fetchall()
    self.data_susbstitute = [d[0] for d in self.data_susbstitute]
    return self.data_susbstitute
```

part of my main code :

```
    def get_select_category():
    get_index = comboExample.current()
    get_index = get_index + 1
    get_index = str(get_index)
    select.select_food(get_index.get_category_food())

def get_category_food():
    comboExample1 = ttk.Combobox(second_window, values=select.select_food(), width=30)
    comboExample1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    comboExample2 = ttk.Combobox(second_window, values=select.select_substitute(), width=30)
    comboExample2.grid(row=0, column=6)
    select.select_food(get_category_food)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    global second_window
    global comboExample
    #creation window
    window = tk.Tk()
    #format window
    window.title("Database OpenFoodFact") 
    window.geometry("950x400")
    #creation title
    label_title = Label(window, text="Bienvenue dans la base de donnée OpenFoodFacts", font=("Helvetica", 40), fg="#41B77F").pack()
    #creation image
    width = 300
    height = 300
    image = PhotoImage(file="/Users/macbookair/Documents/GitHub/PureBeurre/PureBeurre/openfoodfacts-logo-fr-178x150.png")
    canvas = Canvas(window, width=width, height=height)
    canvas.create_image(width/2, height/2, image=image)
    #creation button
    canvas.pack()
    button_connect = tk.Button(window, text="Trouver un aliment à remplacer", command=window.destroy).pack(side=LEFT, padx = 100)
    button_connect2 = tk.Button(window, text="Retrouver mes aliments substitués", command=substitute_food).pack(side=RIGHT, padx = 100)
    # print window
    window.mainloop()
    second_window = tk.Tk()
    second_window.configure(bg="#CECECE")
    second_window.geometry("950x650")
    labelCategory = tk.Label(second_window, text = "Catégories : ", bg="#9E9E9E").grid(row=0, column=0)
    comboExample = ttk.Combobox(second_window, values=select.select_category(), width=30)
    comboExample.grid(row=0, column=1)
    labelFood = tk.Label(second_window, text = "Aliments : ", bg="#9E9E9E").grid(row=2, column=0)
    label_subsitute = tk.Label(second_window, text="Aliments à substituer :", bg="#9E9E9E").grid(row=0, column=5)
    button_choice_food = Button(second_window, text="Valider", command=get_ingredients).grid(row=3, column=1)
    button_choice_category = Button(second_window, text="Valider", command=get_select_category).grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_choice_subsitute = tk.Button(second_window, text="Valider", command=get_substitute).grid(row=1, column=6)
    button_subsitute_food = tk.Button(second_window, text="Substituer aliment", command=saved_substitute, bg="#FAFAFA").grid(row=16, column=6)
    button_subsitute = tk.Button(second_window, text="Historique", command=substitute_food, bg="#FAFAFA").grid(row=16, column=7)
    space = tk.Label(second_window, text="            ", bg="#CECECE"). grid(row=0, column=4)
    second_window.mainloop()
```

Error :   File "interface.py", line 280, in get_select_category
    select.select_food(get_index.get_category_food())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_category_food'

Comment: `get_index = str(get_index)` here you are assigning string to `get_index` you then try to call `get_category_food()` but string doesn't have that method.

Answer (score 0):

In the `select.select_food (get_index.get_category_food ())` line, the `get_index` variable is not an object that has the `get_category_food ()` attribute. You need to revise the code to use the correct object.

Comment: Can you help me with pseudo_code ? because I tried so many thing, I'm lost now